matplotlib pretty print function for numbers
I'm trying to have some nice titles and annotation in matplotlib plots.
For instance, I want to convert a number like 1e-3. in a katex/latex syntax : $1 \cdot 10^{-1}$, which will nicely appears on the plots as 1⋅10
−1
Are you aware of any python module performing that transformation?

You need a raw string: r"$1 \cdot 10^{-1}$". I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate.

The number is in a variable. I don't know it i, advance, so I need a converter.

You can change the tick display with plt.xticks() and use the format r'$...$' to use latex/mathtext:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3)) 

plt.plot(range(10, 1000), range(10, 1000))
plt.xticks([0, 200, 600, 1000],
           [r'$0$', r'$2 \cdot 10^{2}$', r'$6 \cdot 10^{2}$', r'$1 \cdot 10^{3}$'])
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
plt.show()


